# how to call a jquery function of one view in another view codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a header view which is loaded in every view. I have a jquery function in header view and want to use that jquery function in another views jquery function.

Header view jquery function:

```
$('#myAccount').click( function() {
                loadPopupBox();
               $('.login_pop_right').fadeTo('slow',1);
                $("#mdhemadd").attr('disabled',false);
                $("#mdhpass").attr('disabled',false);
           });
```

I want to access it another views jquery function:

```
    $('#shortlist').click(function(){
    var userid = $('#userid').val();
    var dealid = $('#dealid').val();
    if(userid!=''){
        $.ajax({  

            type: "POST",
            url:  "/packagedetails/shortlistdeal",

            data: "userid=" +  userid+"&dealid="+dealid,

            //   data: form_data,
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(obj==true)
                {
   loadShortlistPopupBox();
   $('#shortlistmsg').empty();
    var html='<span class="messageicon"></span><p>Deal shortlisted sucessfullly.</p>';
    $('#shortlistmsg').append(html);
                  //  alert("Deal shortlisted sucessfullly");
                }
                else
                {
  loadShortlistPopupBox();
  $('#shortlistmsg').empty();
    var html='<span class="messageicon"></span><p>This deal cannot be shortlisted.Please check your account for your <a href="/myaccount">shortlisted deals</a>.</p>';
    $('#shortlistmsg').append(html);
              //      alert("This deal cannot be shortlisted.Please check your account for your shortlisted deals.");
                }
            }
        });

    }
    else
    {
    alert("sd");
     $('#myAccount').click();
    }
});
```

How to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create one file with script.js, add this code in it. then include that in every page. so it works

Answer (score 0):

if the header view is loaded in every page, the click event is registering every click already. Instead of creating a new click event in the else statement, pack the code in the click event into a function.

```
 $('#myAccount').click( function() {
    byClick();
 });

 function byClick()
 {
    loadPopupBox();
    $('.login_pop_right').fadeTo('slow',1);
    $("#mdhemadd").attr('disabled',false);
    $("#mdhpass").attr('disabled',false);
 }
```

In the else statement:

```
 else{
    byClick();
 }
```

Comment: how? I want it here else
    {
    alert("sd");
     $('#myAccount').click();
    }
please can you show me?

Comment: Have you tested, if the javascript in the headerview is working correctly in other views